# How to get cell indexpath using item value?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to change the cell background colour, which value is equal to a variable. The variable is date type.

I tried using `cellForItem` but for cellForItem need indexpath. Now how can i get the indexpath of the cell which contains my variable value?

```
let selectedCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: )
selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

Comment: Your datasource and its type? Also, can you tell us more about the variable that you're talking about? It sounds ambiguous without more context :-)

Comment: Why don't you check your `dataSource`? you probably have an array with data lets sat `[1,2,3]` they will be `IndexPath(section: 0, row: enumeratedArrayWhereValueEqualsRequestedValue)`

Comment: When do you change cell's background color? 1 cell or all cell ?

Answer (score 0):

so you can just enumerate through your `dataSource` and get the row.

```
let array: [Int] = [1,2,3]
    var row = 0
    let lookingForThis = 2
    array.enumerated().forEach { (offset, element) in
        if element == lookingForThis {
            row = offset
        }
    }

    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: row, section: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this :

```
TableView.reloadData()
```

then the tableView will be reload you then reload it as you first did and then you have access to your variable using :

```
cell.myVariables
```

or by setting a variable value at the specific indexPath of the cell you want to change the background

```
if (insert a condition here){
    myIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

Then you will have access to the indexPath ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
let row = dataSource.firstIndex(where: { $0 == yourValue })
let section = selectedSection
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
let selectedCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
```